# When can $S \times S$ be partitioned by triples?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, set-partition

Let $S$ be a finite set of $n$ elements. For which $n$ can the Cartesian Product $S\times S$ be partitioned in such a way that elements of the partition are of one of the following forms:

$\{(a,b), (b,c), (c,a)\}$, $\{(a,a), (a,b), (b,a)\}$, or $\{(a,a)\}$

I abbreviate these as the triples $abc, aab, aaa$ respectively, where it is understood that an ordered pair is a member of the triple $x_1x_2x_3$ if the pair is either $(x_1, x_2)$, $(x_2, x_3)$, or $(x_3, x_1)$. Furthermore, I deal with sets of the form $\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$, to allow ease of computation.

It can be shown that this is equivalent to asking if there is a binary operation $*$ on $S$ for which $(a*b)*a=b$ for all $a,b \in S$, where the partitions are given by $(a,b) \in \{(a,b), (b,a*b), (a*b, a)\}$.

Since $+$ is such an operation on the group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times ... \times \mathbb{Z}_2$ (where $\times$ is the direct product), this shows that $n=2^k$ always has such a partition.

However, I have also such partitions for n = 3, 5, and 6, found via brute force computation, given below.

1:
000

2:
000
011

3:
000
012
021
111
222

4: 
000
011
022
033
123
132

5: 
000
011
022
033
044
123
134
142
243

6: 
000
011
022
033
045
054
124
135
143
152
234
253
444
555

I haven't found such partitions for 7 or 9, which leads me to believe that for those n, no such partition exists, however, I don't have any proof. I don't see any obvious pattern, nor can I find a way to generate a larger such partition from a smaller one in some sort of inductive fashion, nor can I find any "classes" of solutions other than $n=2^k$. I started casually working on this problem after working through problem A-1 of the 2001 Putnam Mathematical Competition. I am curious to know if any of you can solve the problem, or failing that, grant any insight into it.

Comment: To me, it seems like the diagonal elements $(a,a)$ help divide the constrained search problem: To partition $S^2$ into triples, first assign each $(a,a)$ to either an $aaa$ triple or an $aba$ triple (and pick the other members.) The rest of $S^2$ must be assignable to $abc$ triples or else the partition fails.

Comment: ...which suggests that you can ignore the $(a,a)$ elements altogether --- the problem reduces to finding a partition of $\{ (a,b) \in S^2 : a\neq b\}$ into pieces of the form $\{(a,b), (b,a)\}$ or $\{(a,b), (b,c), (c,a)\}$. The diagonal elements $(a,a)$ are implicit.

Comment: Is 001 023 032 045 054 066 241 421 265 222 256 163 446 334 361 553 115 a solution for 7?

Comment: There seem to be solutions at least for all $n\le 20$.

Comment: The number of solutions is given by [OEIS-A076016](https://oeis.org/A076016).

Comment: Then the question can also be worded "For which n does there exist a semisymmetric quasigroup of size n".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such partitions always exist.

In the equivalent question about the existence of a semisymmetric quasigroup on $\{0,1,\dots,n-1\}$, you can use the operation defined by
$$ a*b=(-a-b) \bmod n.$$

I found this as answer to question 26(c) in Donald E. Knuth's two days old *The Art of Computer Programming*, Volume 4, [Pre-Fascicle 5C](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/fasc5c.ps.gz) on Dancing links, which I happened to find by once more googling for "semisymmetric quasigroups". It also gives other ways of getting these structures, that the author calls gropes, from groups. Question 26(d) is about the equivalence of these structures and partitions by triples.

Dancing links, by the way, is also the method I used to obtain the results given in my comments to the question.